# Child components don't reflect the changes made to the parent component state

Tags: reactjs, state, use-effect

I have 3 components. The main one has `Decks` state that contains a list of decks with words and a `handleDecks` function with `setDecks` method. I pass the function and a chosen deck from `Decks`  to a child component. That component filters through the deck's  words and passes them down to the third component which is supposed to display the filtered words. The app throws an error because the 3rd component have nothing to display. When I tried debugging the app with `console.log`s I found out that the second component renders twice and its `useEffect()` only runs after the `words` array has been passed down.

The middle component calls the API to update the database. It also makes sure that the app displays up to ten new words to the user.

In there If I delete the filter method from `words` array
initialization or move it into the `useEffect()` the app seems to work but I want the 3rd component to get the filtered array right away and `useEffect()` doesn't run immediately on render.(**UPDATE**: I decided to move the filter method to the  `useEffect()`)

Is there a problem with how I'm trying to manage the state?

1st component:

```
const [deck, setChosenDeck] = useState(1)
const [decks, setDecks] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
        function callAPI() {
            axios
                .get(`http://localhost:8080/deck`)
                .then(response => {
                    const body = response.data;
                    setDecks(body);
                })
        }
        callAPI()
    }, [])
function handleDecksChange(newWord) {
        let newDecks = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(decks))
        let newDeck = newDecks.find(deck => deck.id == chosenDeck)
        newDeck = newDeck.words.map(d => d.id == newWord.id ? newWord : d)
        setDecks(newDecks)
    }
return (<AppPage handleDecksChange={handleDecksChange} deck={decks.find(x => x.id === chosenDeck)} />)
```

2nd component:

```
async function callAPI(id, wordGroup) {
    await axios.put(`http://localhost:8080/word/${id}/${wordGroup}`)
}

export default function LearnNewApp({ deck, handleShowAppChange, handleDecksChange }) {
    let words = deck.words    
    useEffect(() => {
        words = words.filter(x => x.wordGroup == "newLearning")
        let unsubscribed = false;
        if (words.length < 10) {
            let vacant = 10 - words.length
            let newDeck = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(deck))
            let unseenWords = newDeck.words.filter(x => x.wordGroup === "newUnseen")
            for (let i = 0; i < vacant && i < unseenWords.length; i++) {
                let wordUnseenToLearning = unseenWords[i]
                wordUnseenToLearning.wordGroup = "newLearning"
                callAPI(wordUnseenToLearning.id, "newLearning")
                if (!unsubscribed) handleDecksChange(wordUnseenToLearning)
            }
        }
        return () => unsubscribed = true;
    }, []) 
    function memorized(word) {
        callAPI(word.id, "first")
        let wordLearningToFirst = {
            ...word, wordGroup: "first"
        }
        handleDecksChange(wordLearningToFirst)
    }
    function showAgain() {}

    if (words != []) return (
        <CardPage words={words} handleShowAppChange={handleShowAppChange} leftButtonFunc={memorized} rightButtonFunc={showAgain} />
    )
}
```

3rd component:

```
export default function CardPage({ words, handleShowAppChange,leftButtonFunc, rightButtonFunc }) {
    const [currentWord, setCurrentWord] = useState(words[0])
    const [showDefinition, setShowDefinition] = useState(false)


    return (
        <Card>
            <Card.Body>
                {
                    showDefinition ?
                        <>
                            <h4>{currentWord.definition}</h4>
                            <i>{currentWord.example}</i>
                        </>
                        :
                        <Alert onClick={() => setShowDefinition(showDefinition => !showDefinition)}>{"        "}</Alert>
                }
            </Card.Body>

            <Card.Footer>
                <div>
                    <Button onClick={() => leftButtonFunc(currentWord)}>show later</Button>
                    <Button onClick={() => rightButtonFunc(currentWord)}>
                        show again
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </Card.Footer>
        </Card>
    )
}
```

**UPDATE:**
updated the components' code, the problem persists. Still the state doesn't update when it's needed. The app is not responsive. When I am clicking on a button in the 3rd component the db updates but there's no effect on UI.

Comment: Could try: const [decks, setDecks] = useState([])

Comment: @Makogo12 didn't work unfortunately